# iOS Firebase notifications with data

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send push notifications, and i am using the following method in AppDelegate to receive data sent with the notification.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {




        if let firstMessage = userInfo["url"] as? String, let secondMessage = userInfo["category"] as? String {
            print("message1: \(firstMessage)")
            print("message2: \(secondMessage)")

            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController

            mainVC.url = firstMessage
            mainVC.category = secondMessage
            self.window?.rootViewController = mainVC



        }else {

            print("no data received!")
        }



        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

The data is successfully received when app in foreground or in background, but when app is terminated (killed), that notification is received but with no data, as i understand the "didReceiveRemoteNotification", is not called when app is terminated and instead i have to write code in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" to display data received with Push notifications. Any idea how to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps can't received data payload when app is terminated, it is a limitation of iOS. Instead what you can do is set both notification and data payload in FCM and. So if your app is terminated, you still see a notification, and when user taps on the notification, you can receive data payload in didReceiveRemoteNotification function as userInfo, like you are getting when app is in foreground.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your answer, i already used the didReceiveRemoteNotification function to get data from remote notification, after receiving data, the data is sent to a specific ViewController which will display a url received. But it is not working when app is terminated, no data is received. Please check the code in my question where i used the didReceiveRemoteNotification  function. Thanks

Comment: Data is received when notification is tapped. Have both notification key and data key in your firebase cloud message payload

Comment: I am using Firebase Functions to trigger my notification when a value is added to my Firebase Database, in my functio the Payload is like the following: const payload = {

 notification: {
  title: 'title',
  body: 'body',
  badge: '1',
  sound: 'default'
  
  data: {
   
   url: 'https://www.google.com',
   category: 'my category'
  }
 }
 
};

Comment: json looks invalid but i get the gist. Now when is sent and your app is terminated. you should see a notification with title and body, when this notification is tapped / opened, the data part is received in didreceiveremotenotification function, what is the issue here ?

Comment: When user tap the notification, it should take him to a ViewController where i use SafariServices to display a WebPage with the url sent when tapping the notification, this works fine in the app is not terminated. If the app is terminated, the SFSafariViewController is shown but with an empty url.

Comment: I found out the issue, the data is getting received as you previously said, but the problem is that it is taking a very long time till the data is getting received, and the webview is displaying an empty url because the data is not received yet, any ideas how to fix that? Thanks